# What setting is need for SDL_CreateRGBSurface grayscale image?

Tags: c, image, sdl

I am using SDL and I would like to convert an image into grayscale. So what settings should I apply to `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`? I need the grayscale image to be an 8-bit color depth.

Comment: You seem to have swapped full stops and question marks in the text. Fixed that.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. Any idea H2C03 how to prepare the createRGBSurface in SDL ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't. You need to create a new empty surface and read and convert each pixel individually and then copy it to the new surface.

Comment: I believe this is correct. Here is an example - http://www.programmersranch.com/2014/02/sdl2-converting-image-to-grayscale.html